# Differentiate email tracking from Desktop and Mobile versions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, email-tracking

When building emails in Marketing Cloud, we are developing the email "twice" for desktop and mobile but, as far as I know, the tracking is gathering the information from both versions. Is there a way to differentiate the key KPIs like Open and Click rate for mobile and desktop?

Comment: Have you checked in Analytics Builder > Reports? I believe there is a couple of them where you should be able to view email performance per device

Comment: You are right, the Single Email Performance by Device report is what I was looking for. There are two more reports but they are only available in Discover. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Email Performance by Device report is covering that requirement.

Device Performance by Email Sends and Email Performance by Device reports are also fine but only available in Discover.